# Problema con el padding en el navegador Safari para iPhone

Tags: css, safari

El problema es que en dispositivos Iphone al seleccionar un elemento del select pierde el padding left y se ve pegado a la ezquierda dentro del input.

```
 input,
select {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #d0d8e5;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;  
  font-size: 13px;

  @media (max-width: 735px) {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Estuve investigando y me recomendaron ponerlo de esta forma pero sigue de la misma manera, se deberia ver correctamente pero no obtuve resultados.

padding: 0 0 0 20px !important;

Por cierto esta realizado con angular e ionic, pero es el puro html y css, no estoy usando etiquetas de ionic ni nada.

Comment: Ya encontre la solucion, pero me quita el icono, igualmente se puede agregar, con 

-webkit-appearance: none; se arrelga